# What is the most practical way to setup a database for multi-lang content?

Tags: mysql

I'm still learning MySQL and while working on a new project that requires multi-language content, I have stumbled upon a question about the most practical way to design a database that will support this functionality and at the same time be the most efficient database setup.

Table `content_quote`:

```
+--------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field        | Type                  | Null | Key | Default             | Extra                       |
+--------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
| quote_id     | int(11) unsigned      | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment              |
| url_slug     | varchar(255)          | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| author_id    | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| quote        | mediumtext            | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| category     | varchar(15)           | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| likes        | int(11) unsigned      | NO   |     | 0                   |                             |
| publish_time | datetime              | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| locale       | char(5)               | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
+--------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
```

Now here I can just have a standard locale value like `en-US` in the locale field, but I have quite a few tables like that and I'm not sure what is the correct path, either leave it like that OR create a `locale` table to store all the locales and change the current `locale` field to be `tinyint 2` with a Foreign Key going to the new table that stores all the locales.

Example:

```
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------------------+
| Field     | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------------------+
| locale_id | tinyint(2) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| locale    | char(50)            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------------------+
```

More than the answer itself, I'm interested to know what are the advantages/disadvantages of both approaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Advantages and disadvantages of a new `locales` table (they are swapped when NOT a `locales` table is used):

#### Advantages

- Add a list of available locales when some might not be used yet. It allows you to create a dropdown list of available locales in some form.
- Prevent typos since there will be only one `en_US` value available.

#### Disadvantages

- `JOIN` on the new table all the time just to get a string like `en_US`.

---

Keep in mind that space will not be an issue. Don't try to make a decision base on 5 chars vs tiny int size.